# How to get accurate pageCount from a UIPrintFormatter

Tags: ios, printing, uiprintpagerenderer

I'm using a `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` to print some HTML from my app.  It works great if I let the print formatter print to the entire page.

But I want to limit the formatter to printing on one half of the page - and to accomplish this I set the `contentInsets` property once I know the paper size (I set contentInsets when the `UIPrintInteractinControllerDelegate` method `- (UIPrintPaper *)printInteractionController: (UIPrintInteractionController *)pic choosePaper:(NSArray *)paperList` is called.)

This works too - the print is correctly limited to the area of the page defined with the contentInsets.

But the number of printed pages is wrong.  The number of pages I get is as if the print job had been using the default contentInsets (0,0,0,0).

How can I get it to print the correct number of pages?  And why does the `pageCount` property on the `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` always return 0?

Here's the print job setup code:

```
UIPrintInteractionController* pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
pic.delegate = self;

UIPrintInfo* pi = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
pi.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationLandscape;
pi.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGrayscale;
pi.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexNone;
pic.printInfo = pi;

UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter* mtpf = [[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithMarkupText: myHTML ];
pic.printFormatter = mtpf;

[pic presentAnimated: YES completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) 
{
}];
```

and, the delegate method:

```
- (UIPrintPaper *)printInteractionController: (UIPrintInteractionController *)pic choosePaper:(NSArray *)paperList
{
    // we want letter paper
    UIPrintPaper* printPaper = [UIPrintPaper bestPaperForPageSize: CGSizeMake( 612 , 792) withPapersFromArray: paperList];

    UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter* mtpf = (UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter*)pic.printFormatter;

    CGFloat padding = ( printPaper.paperSize.height - printPaper.printableRect.size.height ) / 2.0;

    mtpf.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake( 0, 0, 0, (printPaper.printableRect.size.height / 2.0) + padding );

    // always 0 ???
    NSLog( @"pageCount: %d", mtpf.pageCount );

    return printPaper;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a sub-class of UIPrintPageRenderer. After you set various metrics on the printFormatter in sub-classes numberOfPages method you can get the correct page count. [See my long answer with example code located here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35769422/754494). It's not exactly this problem but it answers a lot of related questions that someone trying to solve printing issues needs to get.